# C# Invoking ListView not working (Background Thread)

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, background

Im working with WinForms.
I want to populate ListView from background thread but when im Invoking listview my program stops and shows an error. The error is "Cannot acces a disposed object. Object name is: ListView." And when i put this method

```
                lvValidate.Invoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    lvValidate.Items.Add(listitem);
                });
```

in a try-catch block my program starts lagging. I dont know where is the problem,but my Invoke method is:

```
static class Intercept
{
    internal static void Invoke(this Control control, Action action)
    {
        control.Invoke(action);
    }
}
```

The error only showing when i close the form and open another form (in the same program). In the Form which contains the ListView the data is unreadable and it seems loads a thousands times.

Here's what my DoWork,ProgressChanged,RunWorkerCompleted event does.

```
        private void bgwLoad_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string commandText = "SELECT * FROM works";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
        connection.Close();
        connection.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        connection.Close();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
            ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["ID"].ToString(), dr["Date"].ToString());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Date"].ToString());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["WorkNumber"].ToString());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["WorkCode"].ToString());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["CoreThread"].ToString());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Tech"].ToString());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["From"].ToString());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["To"].ToString());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Validate"].ToString());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Validate2"].ToString());
            lvValidate.Items.Add(listitem);
        }
    }

    private void bgwLoad_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void bgwLoad_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        picLoading.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Apparently you Disposed of the ListView. Or maybe just of a thing inside it?

Comment: It is unclear what your display technology (and thus ListView) is: WinForms? WPF? ASP.Net? Other?

Comment: Normally I use the report progress method in background mode to send data to the main thread where the ListView is located.  Then in the report progress method send the data to the listview.

Comment: @Christopher WinForms is the technology

Comment: @Christopher i dont know what i've disposed. Manually nothing is disposed in the code.

Comment: @jdweng only dowork runworkercompleted and progresschanged event exists

Comment: Use a "state" (it is a parameter in the event)  variable in the progress changed event to send data (or completed).  Make sure event in handler is main thread.  Then from event send data to the form.  You still need to use the Invoke, but you will not get the cross-thread exception like you are seeing.

Comment: @jdweng which event conatins State variable? And where i need to Invoke which method and what etc. im just learning C#

Comment: @jdweng: I would not advise trying to hand large amounts of Data out of the BackgroundWorker piecemeal/via Progress Reporting. I tried it once. I have only been using ProgressBars since. Actually that there even *is* so much data sounds like a wrong idea. I do have a theory regarding this and the exception.

Comment: @LarryPetshow Are you perhaps retreiving a lot of Database Records using a SQLData Adapter, then try to copy it into the UI's ListView directly?

Comment: @Christopher exactly MySqlDataAdapter and then filling a DataTable then trying to add from DataTable to ListView in background. Because if im not adding from the background the UI will freeze when its loading

Comment: There is an overload ReportProgress(int, object).  I usually make object a class.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I've used it lots of times with no issues.  Often I'm doing queries to databases in background mode in a form project.  I put the results into a datatable and then pass the datatable as a report.  Then display results from the report progress to a DGV.

Comment: `lvValidate` is not a local variable, so it must be something global. | The example just uses the Fill Method, that all DataAdapters inherit from DbDataAdaptet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter#examples | Fill and related functions in turn easily have 1 dozen versions, for all the different Arguments | What you seem to hand around, is actually a "DataSet".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => {
       lvValidate.Items.Add(listitem);
    });
```

EDIT:

Or Try this:

```
 public static void AddItem(ListItem listitem)
    {

        if (lvValidate.InvokeRequired)
        {
            AddItemDelegate d = new AddItemDelegate (AddItem);
            lvValidate.Invoke(d, new object[] { listitem });            
        }
        else
        {
            lvValidate.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                lvValidate.Items.Add(listitem);
            }));
        }            
    } 
delegate void AddItemDelegate(ListItem listitem);
```

Then call:

```
AddItem(listitem);
```

Comment: doesnt work. i've used in DoWork event. it shows cross-thread error 
  Message: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lvValidate' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: same error as before. the backgroundworker is working but when i close the form the program crashes and shows the problem "Cannot acces a disposed object. Object name is: ListView."

Comment: Then you have to store the Data in your calling context from with you are opening the form and pass it every time you open the form.

Comment: you should set the ItemSource in the cunstructor

Comment: i dont know where to do this

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, you are trying to retrieve Data from a DB using a DataAdapter, then handing out the Data piecemeal. This will not work for several reasons:

**DataAdapter**

The DataAdapter Classes all have in common that they only work, while the DBConnection is actively open. That is why you get "Cannot acces a disposed object". Because by the time you try to use it, it the connection is already Disposed. And disposing is not a thing you should ever delay. Or split up at all. Keep the using (that you hopefully got) right where it is, inside the DoWork().

For that reason you always have to copy the data of the DataAdapter into a non-Adapter collection. Really any old list would do. This will temporarily double the Memory load and might procude some stuff for the GC to clean up, but is really they only adviseable way.

**Bulk Writes only in Completed**

While you can theoretically hand out Partial Reads/process results via Progress Reporting, this is not adviseable to try. Writing a GUI has a massive overhead. The first and only time I did that, I ended up locking up my GUI thread with Write and Draw Operations. It looked like I had never done Multitasking. Updating a Progress bar is just about low cost enough to never really cause issues.

The default pattern is to only over write relevant amount of data after you got it all.

If you run into a exception or cancel, the pattern is to asume that all data is faulty and not have it on the UI.

I like to call the BackgroundWorker "Multitasking/-Threading Training Wheels". They teach you all those things. The firt part, by making the handing out akward. The second part, by actually throwing a Exception if you try to use the Result in invalid cases.

**You propably retreive too much**

Perhaps the most common mistake with DB's, is trying to retrieve a lot of data to then do processing or filtering in the Client. A common mistake, so avoid it.

There is a limit to how much data a User can process whatever you would define as 1 page. Never more then 100 Data Fields at once is my advice. If you got do Filtering, Pagination or the sort, *always* do it in the Query. Moving this stuff to the client moves a lot of unesessary data over the Network to then be slower at processing/Filtering then the DB would ever have been.

**Example code**

This actually is my first BGW Project. I updated it a bit over the years, but the bulk of it is still valid:

```
#region Primenumbers
private void btnPrimStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!bgwPrim.IsBusy)
    {
        //Prepare ProgressBar and Textbox
        int temp = (int)nudPrim.Value;
        pgbPrim.Maximum = temp;
        tbPrim.Text = "";

        //Start processing
        bgwPrim.RunWorkerAsync(temp);
    }
}

private void btnPrimCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bgwPrim.IsBusy)
    {
        bgwPrim.CancelAsync();
    }
}

private void bgwPrim_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int highestToCheck = (int)e.Argument;
    //Get a reference to the BackgroundWorker running this code
    //for Progress Updates and Cancelation checking
    BackgroundWorker thisWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    //Create the list that stores the results and is returned by DoWork
    List<int> Primes = new List<int>();


    //Check all uneven numbers between 1 and whatever the user choose as upper limit
    for(int PrimeCandidate=1; PrimeCandidate < highestToCheck; PrimeCandidate+=2)
    {
        //Report progress
        thisWorker.ReportProgress(PrimeCandidate);
        bool isNoPrime = false;

        //Check if the Cancelation was requested during the last loop
        if (thisWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            //Tell the Backgroundworker you are canceling and exit the for-loop
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }

        //Determin if this is a Prime Number
        for (int j = 3; j < PrimeCandidate && !isNoPrime; j += 2)
        {
            if (PrimeCandidate % j == 0)
                isNoPrime = true;
        }

        if (!isNoPrime)
            Primes.Add(PrimeCandidate);
    }

    //Tell the progress bar you are finished
    thisWorker.ReportProgress(highestToCheck);

    //Save Return Value
    e.Result = Primes.ToArray();
}

private void bgwPrim_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbPrim.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void bgwPrim_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbPrim.Value = pgbPrim.Maximum;
    this.Refresh();

    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        //Show the Result
        int[] Primes = (int[])e.Result;

        StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (int Prim in Primes)
        {
            sbOutput.Append(Prim.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        tbPrim.Text = sbOutput.ToString();
    }
    else 
    {
        tbPrim.Text = "Operation canceled by user or Exception";
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: hey im only using DataAdapter for processing the query. the DataAdapter executes and the Data will flow into a DataTable and thats a local thing. and from DataTable i wanna put the Data to a UI ListView. I dont know why it is so hard i just wanna process the Data from DoWork to the UI thread. And im working on this project more than a day and i cannot find a solution. Yours is good but still doesnt work for me

Comment: @LarryPetshow assign the DataTable to the REsult property of the DoWork event. Then retreive it from result in the RunworkerCompleted events. Assign it from there. BGW goes out of it's way and will raise the ReportProgress and RunWorkerCompleted Events on the main thread, so there is no special need for Invoking from those two.

Comment: if im doing this the output(the result) will be System.Data.DataRow. And my ListView filled with this word. But top of that question i've edited and copied the DoWork code.

Comment: @LarryPetshow It has been ages since I used DataAdapter. So beyond that basic part about needing a translation, I do not remember much.